# Powershell param declaration alternatives

Tags: powershell, parameters, declaration

What's the difference between:

```
function foo ([int] i, [string] s) { ... }
```

And:

```
function foo { 
    param (
        [int] i,
        [string] s
    )
    { ... }
}
```

The help on MSDN does not explain this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for convenience, there's no difference. Both ways are valid. Using param (in my opinion) is more readable especially in advanced functions where a parameter declaration may contain a few lines of code and you can use indentation and line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

No difference in this case. You might need to use the `param` declaration for advanced function parameters

Answer (score 1):

Param statements are needed in scripts and scriptblocks, where there's not a natural place to define parameters like there would be in a function.  Manojlds is correct that you have a lot of opportunities to use advanced function "options" to supercharge your function parameters if you use a param statement that you can't use in the more traditional parameter list.